# Unable to insert the information retrieved from a database inside a form

Tags: php, mysql, database, mariadb, nette

I am new to Nette and php frameworks in general.
I am trying to create a form with a selection menu that takes the list of selectable options from a columns inside the database.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Presenters;

use Nette\Application\UI;

class HomepagePresenter extends UI\Presenter
{


     /** @var Nette\Database\Context */

     private $database;

     public function __construct(\Nette\Database\Context $database)
     {
         $this->database = $database;
     }

    protected function createComponentCalculationForm(): UI\Form
    {
        $result=$this->database->query('SELECT supp_name FROM suppliers');
        foreach($result as $supplier){
            $supplierList[]=$supplier;
        }

        $form = new UI\Form;
        $form->addSelect('supplier', 'Dodavatel:',$supplierList);
        $form->addText('quantity', 'Ks')
             ->setRequired()
             ->addRule($form::INTEGER,"Hodnota musí být číslo" )
             ->addRule($form::MIN,'Číslo musí být kladné!',0);
        $form->addText('price', 'Kč')
             ->setRequired()
             ->addRule($form::INTEGER,"Hodnota musí být číslo" )
             ->addRule($form::MIN,'Číslo musí být kladné!',0);
        $form->addButton('calculate', 'Spočítat')
             ->setHtmlAttribute('onclick', 'calculatePrice()');
        $form->addTextArea('result');
        return $form;
    }

}
```

I'd like the $form select menu to include the list of suppliers

Comment: And what's the issue? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: this is the error I get
Recoverable Error

Object of class Nette\Database\Row could not be converted to string search►

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$supplier` variables will contain [`Nette\Database\Row`](https://api.nette.org/3.0/Nette/Database/Row.html), which you store into the `$supplierList` array. [`Form::addSelect`](https://api.nette.org/3.0/Nette/Forms/Container.html#method_addSelect) expects array, where the values are things that can be stringified. Since `Row` does not like to be stringified, you need to add to the list something that does. Extracting the column should work:

```php
        $result = $this->database->query('SELECT supp_name FROM suppliers');
        foreach($result as $supplier){
            $supplierList[] = $supplier['supp_name'];
        }
```